# Creating tls-trust-store for gmail account via IMAP in Mule ESB

Tags: imap, mule, esb, mule-studio

I have problem creating tls-trust-store for connecting to the gmail account via IMAP in  Mule ESB
If I delete "path" and "storePassword" fields in the  imaps:tls-client and imaps:tls-trust-store tags I 
can connect, but them I have to delete it every time I've change anything in the xml, cause Mule recreate this fields. 
I've tried to get the key via openssl and create key via keytool application - but I've not succeed.
Can anyone help me with the right way how to create such things?

Answer (score 0):

> Mule recreate this fields

Mule doesn't alter your XML configuration ever. You're apparently dealing with Mule Studio bug that makes it remove valid XML configuration elements. This is a known faulty behaviour of Studio that is generally well known and being worked on fixing.